# react-multi-crousel is stretching indefinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, slideshow

I tried to implement crousel in my website. For it I used react-multi-crousel.

```
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

 function Blog(props){

    const responsive = {
        desktop: {
           breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
          items: 3,
          slidesToSlide: 3 // optional, default to 1.
        },
        tablet: {
          breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
          items: 2,
          slidesToSlide: 2 // optional, default to 1.
        },
        mobile: {
          breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
          items: 1,
          slidesToSlide: 1 // optional, default to 1.
        }
      };

 
  

console.log(props.blog.fetchedData)
return(
    <div>
       
            
        

<Carousel responsive={responsive}>
            <div>num 1</div>
            <div>num 2</div>
            <div> num 3</div>
            <div>num 4</div>
            <div>num 5</div>
            <div>num 6</div>
      
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Blog;
```

When I load the page, crousel item starts to expand like in the gif. I copied the code from the docs. And I have no idea what went wrong. How to solve this problem. Please help.
[image: Please help me to solve this problem]